# KMS rotation process

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms

I want to implement an envelope encryption using KMS.

I would encrypt few properties in a no sql db, is the first time that I'm doing it and for what I have read I will need to save my encrypted data key along the data.

My question is, at some point I would like to rotate the CMK key that KMS is using to encrypt the data key, for that scenario, I would need to write a process to re-encrypt my data key with the new CMK that KMS will use?, do I need to change the encrypted data key with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would need to write a process to re-encrypt my data key with the new CMK that KMS will use?, do I need to change the encrypted data key with a new one?

If you use **automated** rotation, you don't have to do anything in terms of data keys. They are not affected by rotation. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html):

> automatic key rotation has **no effect** on the data that the KMS key protects. It does not rotate the data keys that the KMS key generated or re-encrypt any data protected by the KMS key, and it will not mitigate the effect of a compromised data key.

But if you use **manual** rotation, you may have to re-encrypt everything. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/):

> If you manually rotate your imported or custom key store keys, you may have to **re-encrypt your data** depending on whether you decide to keep old versions of keys available.